# "ErrorException Array to string conversion" when submitting a form

Tags: php, laravel

I am trying to submit a form but it showed me "ErrorException Array to string conversion" in line `generalForm::create($input);`

```
    public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $input = $request->all();
        $input['services'] = $request->input('services');
        $input['needs'] = $request->input('needs');
        generalForm::create($input);
        return redirect()->route('/');  
    }
```

Comment: Please visit [help], take [tour] to see what and [ask].

Answer (score 0):

when you use `$input = $request->all();`, data is array and contain array of services, so you can store in directly if services filed exists on db and is array

```
generalForm::create($input);
return redirect()->route('/');
```